# Pytorch Custom Dataset with multiple return datatypes

Tags: pytorch, dataset, pytorch-dataloader

I am writing a custom torch Dataset for my problem. For each sample, I would like to return an integer, a list of 10 floats and a boolean. What is the most efficient way to deal with this?

So in the `__getitem__()` function should I return each element separately like `return int, list, bool` or for example packed in a tuple `return (int, list, bool)`?

Answer (score 1):

Returning "separately" will default to returning a *tuple*.

Comment: I just tried it and your are right, so no difference in behavior there.